# apache+mod-wsgi:ImportError: No module named site

Tags: python, centos7, mod-wsgi

I created two python versions on my server and assigned my project to the python version of the virtual environment.but getting that

> ImportError: No module named site

Where am I doing wrong?

Some notes:

> centos7
>   python3
>   mod-wsgi

httpd.conf:

```
WSGIPythonHome "/usr/local/python3/bin/oway/lib/python3.7/site-packages"
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/oway/mall_stock:/usr/local/python3/bin/oway/lib/python3.7/site-packages

<VirtualHost *:80>
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/oway/mall_stock/mall_stock/wsgi.py
  #WSGIDeamonProcess oway python-path=/usr/local/python3/bin/oway/lib/python3.7/site-packages
  #WSGIProcessGroup oway
  LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
  ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/oway"
  ServerName www.owaycare.com
  ServerAlias owaycare.com
  Alias /static /var/www/html/oway/mall_stock/static
  Alias /media /var/www/html/oway/mall_stock/media
  Redirect permanent "/" "https://www.owaycare.com/"

  <Directory /var/www/html/oway/mall_stock/static>
   Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/html/oway/mall_stock/media>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /var/www/html/oway/mall_stock>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

wsgi.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import sys
import site
site.addsitedir('/usr/local/python3/bin/oway/lib/python3.7/site-packages')
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mall_stock.settings')

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

path = '/var/www/html/oway/mall_stock'
if path not in sys.path:
   sys.path.append(path)
```

Comment: Why do you need this `addsitedir`?

Answer (score -1):

The virtual environment does not specify a python version